# can't shut down or reboot ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, intel

i just bought an asus k550vx-dm108t with a intel skylake cpu, and have some troubles trying to shut down or suspend the pc on ubuntu 16.04 (or, at least, these are the main problems).

I've already read lots of topics like mine, updated OS and the bios, and tried different ways without success:

- "shutdown -h now"
- modifing etc/default/grub, adding "reboot=pci" or "acpi=force" and "apm=power_off" (or something similar)
- modifing etc/modules adding "apm power_off=1"

sometimes it worked, with no troubles while shutting down, but after some boots it stucks at a black screen, does anyone know what can i do?

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

try out `reboot -p` and if you lazy to write reboot -p to the terminal every time, you can create a .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ShutDown
Icon=Directory/to/the/icon
Exec=reboot -p
Type=Application
```